# Multiple routes with the same anonymous callback using Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim

How can I define multiple routes that use the same anonymous callback?

```
$app->get('/first_route',function()
{
   //Do stuff
});
$app->get('/second_route',function()
{
   //Do same stuff
});
```

I know I can use a reference to a function which would work, but I'd prefer a solution for using the anonymous function to be consistent with the rest of the codebase.

So basically, what I'm looking for is a way of doing something like this:

```
$app->get(['/first_route','/second_route'],function()
{
       //Do same stuff for both routes
});
```

~ OR ~

```
$app->get('/first_route',function() use($app)
{
   $app->get('/second_route');//Without redirect
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use conditions to achieve just that. We use that to translate URLs.

```
$app->get('/:route',function()
{
    //Do same stuff for both routes
})->conditions(array("route" => "(first_route|second_route)"));
```

Answer (score 14):

I can't give you a framework specific solution, but if it helps you can reference anonymous function:

```
$app->get('/first_route', $ref = function()
{
   //Do stuff
});
$app->get('/second_route', $ref);
```

Comment: That's very clever, thanks. I'll wait to see if there's a framework specific solution.

Answer (score 4):

Callbacks are delegates. So you can do something like that :

```
$app->get('/first_route', myCallBack);
$app->get('/second_route', myCallBack);

function myCallBack() {
    //Do stuff
}
```