# How to get /, /article to map to same action in PHP Slim

Tags: php, slim

I want to map two routes : / and /articles to the same method list_articles.

I tried using this code but it's not working.

```
 $app->get('/:route', function () use($app, $layout) {
    list_articles();
 })->conditions(array("route" => "(/|articles)"))->name('list_articles');
```

What am I typing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "action"? `name` is used to give a name to your route so you can use it with `urlFor`...

Comment: Or sorry I had some typos there. What I want to do is map these two routes (/ and /articles) to the method invocation list_articles(). However, this example is not working. What am I typing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "method invocation"? `name` doesn't map to a method AFAIK, it just gives a name to your route to identify it later. I think you're looking for "route middleware". Another option is passing the common function into the anonymous callback.

Comment: The 'name' method gives the route a name to use in $app->urlFor(). I was using [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521264/multiple-routes-with-the-same-anonymous-callback-using-slim-framework/15772104#15772104) I want to be able to use the same code but have it load the '/' route.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add the document root (/) to the list of routes. It says "do stuff" for both / and /articles.

```
 $app->get('/:route', function () use($app, $layout) {
     echo "do stuff"
 })->conditions(array("route" => "(|articles)"))->name('list_articles');
```

The

```
 ->name('list_articles')
```

part just names the route to be 'list_articles'