# SLIM API: Multiple/Alternative routes for same action

Tags: php, api, slim

We are building an API using the SLIM framework. Within our API hierarchy, some specific actions will be available with multiple paths. Here is an example:

```
$app->get('/surveys/:sid/contacts/:cid', function ($sid, $cid) use ($user) {
    // Do stuff
});

OR

$app->get('/contacts/:cid/surveys/:sid', function ($cid, $sid) use ($user) {
    // Do same stuff
});
```

We have already seen some approaches (e.g. [Multiple routes with the same anonymous callback using Slim Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521264/multiple-routes-with-the-same-anonymous-callback-using-slim-framework)) and were able to do this by referencing the anonymous function.

```
$app->get('/surveys/:sid/contacts/:cid', $ref = function ($sid, $cid) use ($user) {
    // Do stuff
});

AND

$app->get('/contacts/:cid/surveys/:sid', $ref); // Calls the same stuff, but with different order of arguments (wrong)
```

But how can we handle the **changing order of passed arguments** ("$sid, $cid" and "$cid, $sid")?

Thank you!

---

Thank you Andrew Smith for your answer! We will use a slightly different implementation:

```
function doStuff($user, $sid, $cid) {
    // Do stuff
}

$app->get('/surveys/:sid/contacts/:cid', function ($sid, $cid) use ($user) {
    doStuff($user, $sid, $cid);
});

$app->get('/contacts/:cid/surveys/:sid', function ($cid, $sid) use ($user) {
    doStuff($user, $sid, $cid);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the same function, there isn't really a way of doing this besides creating another function that would call the first function. See example below.

```
<?php

function firstFunction ($sid, $cid) {
    // Do stuff
};

function secondFunction ($cid, $sid) {
    return firstFunction($sid, $cid);
};

$app->get('/surveys/:sid/contacts/:cid', 'firstFunction');

$app->get('/contacts/:cid/surveys/:sid', 'secondFunction');
```

Comment: We will use a slightly different approach (added below the question), but this is basically the answer. Your answer, however, does not include the $user variable, does it? Thanks anyway!